# How can i write a function that generates children from parents in a recursive way?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I want to recursevly generate a graph thath starts from (for example) [0,0,0] and generate his children: [1,0,0], [0,1,0] and [0,0,1].
Then theese children will become parents so we'll have (from [1,0,0]) -> [2,0,0], [1,1,0], [1,0,1] and so on until the i iteration.

The code that i've implemented, given the child generator function (that generate children) is this:

```
    positions = numpy.array(list(range(k))) + 1;
    minimum_targets = [];
    tau = list(numpy.zeros(len(p)-1));
    ls1 = []
    ls1.append(tau)
    ls=[]
    
    
    
    
    
    initial = 1
    l = 0
    i = 1
    
        
    
    # Parte la prima iterazione e genera padre [0,0,0] e figli con le possibili permutazioni [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]
    graph, root = child_generator_2(len(p), i, p ,a, tau)
    
    temp = copy.copy(root)
    temp_root = copy.copy(root)
    i = 2
    while i <= 5:
        
        l = 0
    # forse lo devi fare con i while perché ti serve un contatore:   
    
        while l < len(list(temp.children)):
            
            graph, root = child_generator_2(len(p), i, p ,a, list(temp.children)[l].name)
            temp.children[l].children = root.children
            
            
            for elemento in list(temp.children[l].children):
                    
                graph,root = child_generator_2(len(p), i+1, p ,a, elemento.name)
    
                elemento.children = root.children
                
        
                    
             
            l = l + 1
        temp = copy.copy(temp.children[l-1])
            
        
        
        i = i + 1;
```

can you please give me a simple code example (with this structure) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a script to simulate your idea. However, I don't know wether you can repeat nodes in the graph or they must be unique. As you didn't specify it must be a tree, the problem becomes ambiguous.

In order to solve this problem, I've placed a flag that allows you to choose wether the nodes that will be generated should be unique or not.

If the **nodes are not unique**, whenever a new node is requested, it will be generated and inserted at the graph, even if it already exists inside the graph. This way, each node will contain only one parent at a time. This allows you to generate a tree structure.

[image]

If the **nodes are unique**, copies of them will not be inserted on the graph. This means that one node might have more than one parent at the same time. Just like this:

[image]

Here's the script I've made (**Edit:** added flag `add_child_of_self` on script to flag wether nodes should add a copy of themselves as child.):

```
def pattern(node, index):
    pat = []

    for n in node:
        pat.append(n)

    pat[index] += 1

    return tuple(pat)

# Edit: Added 'DepthLevel' property to all nodes, which equals to variable depth. 
# It helps to diferentiate nodes with same label in different depths of the graph / tree.
def generate_graph(nodes, parent, node, depth, nodes_unique=False, add_child_of_self=False):
    if (depth > 0):
        nChildren = range(len(node))

        if (nodes_unique):
            found = False
            for nd in nodes:
                if (nd['Node'] == node['Node']):
                    found = True
                    print(node['Node'], [p['Node'] for p in node['Parent']])
                    node = nd
                    break
            if (not found):
                nodes.append(node)
        else:
            nodes.append(node)

        if (parent is not None):
            parent['Children'].append(node)
            node['Parent'].append(parent)

        for i in nChildren:
            child = pattern(node['Node'], i)
            generate_graph(nodes, node, {"Node": child, "Children": [], "Parent": []}, depth-1, nodes_unique, add_child_of_self)

        # Add Self Node as Child of Self
        if (add_child_of_self):
            child = node['Node']
            generate_graph(nodes, node, {"Node": child, "Children": [], "Parent": []}, depth-1, nodes_unique, add_child_of_self)

        node['DepthLevel'] = depth
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = {"Parent": [], "Node": (0, 0, 0), "Children": []}
    nodes = []

    # Regarding the parameter: nodes_unique
    #
    # If nodes are not unique (False), all parents may contain a 
    # set of children, and each child will be linked to a single parent.
    #
    # --------------------------------------------------------
    #
    # If nodes are unique (True), repeated nodes will not be reiserted
    # in the nodes list. This means that if a repeated node is requested,
    # its reference from nodes list will be taken.
    #
    # As new instances of the same node will not be generated, nodes
    # might come from different parents at the same time.
    
    # Edit: By Setting add_child_of_self as True, parents can now add a child with their own label into the graph.
    generate_graph(nodes, None, root, 3, nodes_unique=False, add_child_of_self=True)

    # Edit: I modified the output printing to show more information from the graph on each node.
    sorted_nodes = reversed(sorted(nodes, key=lambda nd: nd['DepthLevel']))
    for nd in sorted_nodes:
        print('%s (DepthLevel: %i):' % (str(nd['Node']), nd['DepthLevel']))
        if (len(nd['Parent']) > 0):
            print('    Parents:')

            index = 0
            for parent in nd['Parent']:
                print('      [%i]: {%s ~ DepthLevel: %i}' % (index, str(parent['Node']), parent['DepthLevel']))
                index += 1
        else:
            print('    No Parents.')

        print()
        if (len(nd['Children']) > 0):
            print('    Children:')

            index = 0
            for child in nd['Children']:
                print('      [%i]: {%s ~ DepthLevel: %i}' % (index, str(child['Node']), child['DepthLevel']))
                index += 1
            print()
        else:
            print('    No Children.')

        print()
```

**Edit:** Output below now contains the flag `add_child_of_self = True`

Output when nodes are not unique `nodes_unique=False` (single parenting):

```
(0, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 3):
    No Parents.

    Children:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}
      [1]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 2}
      [3]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}


(0, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 2):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}


(0, 0, 1) (DepthLevel: 2):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 1, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 2) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}


(0, 1, 0) (DepthLevel: 2):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(1, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 2, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 1, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}


(1, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 2):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(2, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(1, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(1, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}


(0, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 0, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 1, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(1, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 0, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 0, 2) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 1, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(1, 0, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 1, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 1, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(0, 2, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(1, 1, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(1, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(1, 0, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(1, 1, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.

(2, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 2}

    No Children.
```

Output when the nodes are unique `nodes_unique=True` (multi parenting):

```
(0, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 3):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}
      [1]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}
      [4]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [5]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [6]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [7]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}


(0, 0, 2) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}

    No Children.

(0, 0, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}
      [1]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 1, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 2) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}


(0, 1, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}

    No Children.

(0, 2, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}

    No Children.

(0, 1, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}
      [1]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(1, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 2, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 1, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}


(1, 0, 1) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}

    No Children.

(1, 1, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(0, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}

    No Children.

(2, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}

    No Children.

(1, 0, 0) (DepthLevel: 1):
    Parents:
      [0]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}
      [1]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(0, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 3}

    Children:
      [0]: {(2, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [1]: {(1, 1, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [2]: {(1, 0, 1) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
      [3]: {(1, 0, 0) ~ DepthLevel: 1}
```

I made these images on GIMP using the output of each execution. That's what each console print is telling you.

Comment: The solution with unique nodes, is certanly more efficient to be generated.

What if i have to navigate this graph, from leaves to the root, in order to gerate unique paths? (Because for my application i need to generate all possible combinations of paths from root to the leaves, chosing 1 child for each generation)

I'm sorry for English

Thanks for your answering

Comment: The idea is not really hard to do it, but this algorithm also requires recursion. So, it's very difficult to write the script into the comment section.

Comment: Try to post another question for that.

Comment: Or search about it, there's lots of examples on the internet showing how to get paths from a graph, with and without loops. In this case the answer is easier as the graph generated by this script does not make any loop.

Comment: And what if a parent can generate a child equal to imself? What  can be a possible condition? (not with unique nodes)

Comment: See the edit I made on the answer.